# Excel Index Match Returning #N/A if Any Date in a Range is False

Tags: excel

I am attempting to search for the most common item in a column based on a date range. Whenever a date is not in the range specified, it returns false and causes the #N/A error. Is there a way to prevent this?

The formula I am using is:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Topic],MODE(IF(AND(Table1[Date Entered]>=DATE(2018,3,1)), MATCH(Table1[Topic],Table1[Topic],0))))
```

This works as expected as my first data point is on 3/1/2018, but if the DATE() function is changed to a later date, all earlier dates return FALSE according to formula evaluation which seems to cause the error.

Edit: The error appears only when using less than and not greater than

The expected output should be a string from the topic list.

Comment: Do you want to just hide the error?

Comment: Can you also provide some sample data with expected outcome?

Comment: The data will be a string pulled form the Topic column from Table1, such as "Compliments" or "Complaints"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the 'AND' because even if the formula is entered as an array formula, it's only evaluating the condition for the the first row of the array, so the result (if the date is changed to a later date) is always false.

```
=INDEX(Table1[Topic],MODE(IF(Table1[Date Entered]>=DATE(2018,3,1), MATCH(Table1[Topic],Table1[Topic],0))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is good and how I initially set it up, but if I want to search for a date range, it always results in an error. due to the less than function it requires.